# Laravel union 500 error when assigning query

Tags: php, laravel

So I have the following code...

```
$query = DB::table('recipes');

// USING ONE OF THE FF STATEMENTS CHANGES THE OUTPUT
$second = DB::table('recipes'); // WORKS
$second = $query; // BREAKS AND RETURNS 500 ERROR

$query->where('status', 0);
$query->where('type', 'x');

$second->where('status', 0);
$second->where('type', 'y');

return $second->union($query)->toSql(); // toSql ONLY FOR DEBUG
```

I'm just trying to wrap my head around why this would be erroring despite assigning the value is essentially the same query builder object.

Comment: wait a minute, [`where`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_where) accepts 3 parameters, 1) the column, 2) operator, 3) value. on your code it only had 2, and it confuses me. does `toSql()` result in 500?

Comment: Without the operator it defaults to an equals operator

Comment: you are right, the [default operator is =](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L648). thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query might be identical to your current attempt, and is much simpler:

```
$query = DB::table('recipes')
    ->where('status', 0)
    ->whereIn('type', ['x', 'y']);
    ->get();
```

If, for some reason, you really wanted to use a union here, then you will have to fix your syntax:

```
$first = DB::table('recipes')
        ->where('status', 0);
        ->where('type', 'x');

$second = DB::table('recipes')
        ->where('status', 0);
        ->where('type', 'y');
        ->union($first)
        ->get();
```

Note that you might really intend to be doing a `UNION ALL` here.

Comment: I'm trying to create a dynamic version of this as it's going to be for a filter. Is there any reason why I cant go 


```
$first = $second = DB::table('recipes');
        
        $first->where('status', 0)
        ->where('type', 'McCormick Official');

        $second
        ->where('status', 0)
        ->where('type', 'User Submitted')
        ->union($first);
```

Comment: Then maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do here.  You should add sample data at this point which helps to explain your problem.

Comment: Originally I was going to use an array of queries then union them, either through union or union all. However, it errors when I try to assign the main query being $query = DB::table('recipes') to the array, however hardcoding it allows it to work.

That being said this whereIn is exactly what I needed. And a much much more elegant solution to what originally was the problem thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have `$second` and `$query` pointing to the same exact Query Builder instance because of the assignment:

```
$second = $query;
```

This does not create a new copy of `$query` and assign it to `$second`; this is assignment by reference. To copy the object you would want to clone the Builder:

```
$second = clone $query;
```

When you assign the result of `DB::table(...)` to `$second` that is a new Builder object being assigned. When you do the direct assignment of `$second` to `$query` you end up with the equivalent statement at the end of:

```
return $query->union($query)->toSql();
```

This is going to create a recursive loop I would assume and take down the process eventually.

[PHP: Assignment Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

[PHP: Object Cloning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: I was wondering why my single query had way too many where queries. Does this only happen to objects? I've never really needed to make clones of my objects before.

Thanks for the information!